# How to extract Month and Year from column in PowerBI powerquery

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a column (monthyear) in the image below. I want to extract the Month and year from the column to put it in the new column. Note: In my dataset this information goes for every day of the year

So the new column would look like:
01/2020
01/2020
01/2020
etc.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In Power Query, use some of the [date functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-functions).

To get the year it will be

```
Date.Year([monthyear])
```

For the month, it will depend on how you want to format it. Using the month of June as an example:

To get 'Jun'

```
Date.ToText([monthyear],"MMM")
```

To get the month number in the format 06

```
Number.ToText(Date.Month([monthyear]), "00")
```

Just to get the number 6 it will be:

```
Date.Month([monthyear])
```

In DAX use the [date functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/date-and-time-functions-dax)

For year the calculated column will be:

```
YEAR([monthyear])
```

For the month:

```
MONTH([monthyear])
```

I would always do a much data transformation in Power Query when you can before it gets to the data model.